# LISP programming - Curious to know what that code does

Tags: lisp, elisp, clisp

```
(defun interleave (x y)
  (cond ((and (null x)(null y)) nil)
        (t (cons (car x) (cons (car y) (interleave (cdr x) (cdr y)))))
```

Curious to know what above code does ?

Answer (score 7):

It defines a function that interleaves two lists.
For example, calling it as follow:

```
(interleave '(a b c) '(d e f))
```

will give the list `(a d b e c f)`.

**Edit**

Here is the explanation:

- `(defun interleave (x y) ..` declare the function `interleave` which accept 2 arguments (or lists)
- `(cond ((and (null x)(null y) nil) ...)` tells that if *both* `x` and `y` are `nil`, return `nil`. `nil` is the empty list and the function `null` checks if a list is empty or not. Here, the condition acts as a termination for a recursive call of the `interleave` function.
- `(t ...)` specify the default action if the above condition is not met
- `(cons ...)` constructs a new list by specifying the head (first argument) and the tail (second argument) of the list. For example: `(cons a '(b c))` will give `(a b c)`. Note that the head should be a single element and the tail a list of elements. One useful property of `cons` here is: `(cons a nil) => (a)`.
- `(car x)` retrieve the head of the list `x`. For example: `(car '(a b c))` will return `a`. One useful property of `car` here is: `(car nil) => nil`.
- `(cdr x)` retrieve the tail of the list `x`. For example: `(cdr '(a b c))` will return `(b c)`. Useful propertie of `cdr` here are:

  - tail of a list of one element is `nil`: `(cdr (a)) => nil`
  - tail of `nil` is `nil`: `(cdr nil) => nil`.
- `(interleave (cdr x) (cdr y))` calls the `interleave` function recursively with the **tail** of both `x` and `y` as arguments.

So, for the call `(interleave '(a b c) '(d e f))`, the recursion can be represented as follow

```
(interleave '(a b c) '(d e f))
(cons a (cons d (interleave (b c) (e f)))
(cons a (cons d (cons b (cons e (interleave (c) (f))))))
(cons a (cons d (cons b (cons e (cons c (cons f (interleave nil nil)))))))
(cons a (cons d (cons b (cons e (cons c (cons f nil))))))
(cons a (cons d (cons b (cons e (cons c (f))))))
(cons a (cons d (cons b (cons e (c f)))))
(cons a (cons d (cons b (e c f))))
(cons a (cons d (b e c f)))
(cons a (d b e c f))
(a d b e c f)
```

For the case where the length of the two lists are not equal, we have for example:

```
(interleave '(a b c) '(1 0))
(cons a (cons 1 (interleave (b c) (0))))
(cons a (cons 1 (cons b (cons 0 interleave (c) nil))))
(cons a (cons 1 (cons b (cons 0 (cons c (cons nil (interleave nil nil)))))))
(cons a (cons 1 (cons b (cons 0 (cons c (cons nil nil))))))
(cons a (cons 1 (cons b (cons 0 (cons c (nil))))))
(cons a (cons 1 (cons b (cons 0 (c nil)))))
(cons a (cons 1 (cons b (0 c nil))))
(cons a (cons 1 (b 0 c nil)))
(cons a (1 b 0 c nil))
(a 1 b 0 c nil)
```

Comment: The corner cases are interesting too, like with inputs (a b c) and (0 1)

Comment: So what is condition 2 is doing. Can you please explain                                                              (t (cons (car x) (cons (car y) (interleave (cdr x) (cdr y)))))  ?

Comment: Added few explanations in the answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation